# не удается открыть источник "cuda_runtime.h"

Tags: c++, файлы, cuda

пытаюсь попробовать данный пример https://github.com/jordanbonilla/Read_GPU_Temperature_CUDA/blob/master/read_temps.cu, копирую код, вставляю, CUDA установлен, в свойствах решения добавил путь к этому заголовку, даже добавил этот файл в "Файлы заголовков", но ошибка не уходит. Использую VS 2017. Что ещё нужно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пробовали заменить <...> такие скобки в include на такие : ”...” ?

Comment: // Must be running on a UNIX machine - вот в коде написана такая рекомендация, а Вы пишете, что указали что-то в свойствах решения. Вы случайно не в MSVS работаете, может у Вас конфликт какой-то с требованием Unix-системы?

Comment: Значит путь указан не верно...

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, [mcve].

Comment: какой путь ещё нужно добавить?

Comment: и "..." и <...> пробовал

Comment: Какой путь в файловой системе к этому файлу и какой путь прописан в настройках проекта? Использовать следует `<>`