# как добавить ссылку к проекту?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь использовать CUDA библиотеки от NVIDIA, все установил. Нужно к обычному проекту на c++ добавить ссылку на библиотеку из CUDA, но при добавлении ссылки нет кнопки "Обзор". Может в параметрах проекта есть эта функция, подскажите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ссылка для этого дела нужна [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для подключения сторонних библиотек следует прописывать пути к инклюдам для компилятора и пути к библиотекам для линкера.

Comment: Какую "ссылку" вам надо добавить и зачем?

Comment: @VTT как это сделать? Я утонул в этих свойствах, везде все папки по передобавлял, но компилятор не видит библиотеку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я добавил скрин, для чего и зачем.

Comment: Это не "ссылка". Правильные термины и способ решения проблемы @VTT указал.

Comment: Приведите пути, по которым находятся установленные инклюды и библиотеки cuda. Приведите пути, которые вы добавили в настройки проекта. И не следует создавать [дубликаты вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751655/не-удается-открыть-источник-cuda-runtime-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скрину у вас не прописаны пути до инклюдов. Нужно зайти в свойства проекта "Configuration Properties"->"C/C++"->"General" Там поле "Aditional Include Directories"

И пути к библиотекам для линковки: "Configuration Properties"->"Linker"->"General" Там поле "Aditional Library Directories".

"Configuration Properties"->"Linker"->"Input" В поле "Aditional Dependencies" указываются сами библиотеки

Это все в VisualStudio2015, но я думаю во всех также